# Using const values in factory class to choose implementation

Tags: c#

I am creating a small program to parse the contents of Excel files. There are two types of Excel files, containing the same data, but with different templates.

It is possible to tell them apart with 100% certainty by checking the contents of a specific cell, which I call the `fingerprint`.

---

Follows an MVCE:

- Creates an `A` if the fingerprint contains `foo`
- Creates a `B` if the fingerprint contains `bar`

Interesting data (Two characters on the left/right depending on the class) is then displayed. (Obviously the real use case is more complex than extracting data from the fingerprint. In some cases, I want to get the content of column A, in some cases, it is first word in column B, concatenaned with column D, etc.)

However, should I ever want to add a new implementation, where is interesting data is, say, the middle two characters, I would need to modify the `Create item` function as well.

I have tried to find a way to loop through all implementations of the base class, and make it automatic, but figured the cure was worse than the disease...

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var factory = new Factory();

        var test1 = factory.CreateItem("something foo");
        Console.WriteLine(test1.GetInterestingData());


        var test2 = factory.CreateItem("something bar");
        Console.WriteLine(test2.GetInterestingData());
    }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    protected readonly string Data;
    public Base(string data){
        this.Data = data;
    }
    public abstract string GetInterestingData();
}

public class A:Base
{
    public const string Fingerprint = "Foo";
    public A(string data):base(data){}

    public override string GetInterestingData(){
        return this.Data.Substring(0,2);
    }
}

public class B:Base
{
    public const string Fingerprint = "Bar";
    public B(string data):base(data){}

    public override string GetInterestingData(){
        return this.Data.Substring(this.Data.Length - 2,2);
    }
}   

public class Factory
{
    public Base CreateItem(string data){
        if(data.Contains(A.Fingerprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){
            return new A(data);
        }
        if(data.Contains(B.Fingerprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){
            return new B(data);
        }
        throw new Exception("No fingerprint match");
    }
}
```

Comment: So... What is your question/concern?

Comment: It looks fine as it is really

Comment: I don't understand this post, What has the code todo with Excel? What has a class hierarchy here to do with the initial problem described? I am not even sure if this is a coding question, or a conceptual one. Voting to close with the "needs more clarity" reason. If your intend was to ask a coding question, please don't invest more time here to add clarifications, coding questions are off-topic on this site. Instead delete your question here first, then ask a better one on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @DocBrown The code has nothing to do with Excel. It's just to put the conceptual question that follows in context.
The gist of it is: I have an input dataset. How the input dataset is parsed is determined at runtime by the dataset itself. 

How can I do things to ensure I can add more ways to parse the data in the future without too much hassle.

Comment: @Jean-Pierre: ok, you should edit this information to your question, not bury it here in a comment. I think I begin to understand what you are after, it seems you are looking for a solution where you are trying to achieve extendibility by subclassing - which is not obvious, you should explain this ia little bit better why you are trying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The concrete type's responsibility

Though it may seem that the `Fingerprint` property belongs to the derived classes (as they are used as an identifying value for this class), they don't actually belong there.

It's the *factory*'s responsibility to identify the correct derived class to be used. The derived classes themselves don't quite care about how they get identified. To showcase that point, imagine if you have several new data sources which use a totally different distinction method (fingerprint).

Should your derived classes now incorporate all possible fingerprints? What if there are overlaps between them? This problem quickly grows out of proportion because the derived classes are trying to take on a responsibility which isn't theirs to take on.

---

### The factory's responsibility

As a slightly more generalized aside which helps in understanding the core of this answer (and your problem):

There are three steps to the work that needs to be done here:

1. Identify the needed concrete type
2. Instantiate the concrete type
3. Use the instantiated object (polymorphically)

By default, classes are responsible for their own initialization logic (step 2), i.e. the constructor. However, factories specifically exist to take over that responsibility. This is often done specifically because two or more classes' initialization logic needs to be streamlined, though that is not the *only* use case.

When the responsibility of step 2 is handled by the factory, it makes little sense to still involve the concrete types themselves in step 1 (which is what you're currently doing with the `Fingerprint` property). It makes little sense to go from the concrete type to the factory and then back to the concrete type.

Think about what your factory's responsibility is. Deciding which concrete type to use is pretty much *exactly* why you've implemented this factory. Therefore, any logic pertaining to that decisionmaking process belongs to the factory, properly encapsulated.

---

### A solution

The solution here is to contain this distinction method in the factory itself. Several implementations exist. Since you're able to rely on a reusable `Contains` logic, it can be as simple as this:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<string, Base>> mappings = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, Base>>()
{
    { "Foo", data => new A(data) },
    { "Bar", data => new B(data) },
}

public Base CreateItem(string data)
{
    foreach(var mapping in mappings)
    {
        if(data.Contains(mapping.Key))
        {
            var createItemMethod = mapping.Value;
            return createItemMethod(data);
        }

        throw new Exception("No mapping was found!");
    }
}
```

*I used inline lambdas for this because the creation logic is trivial. If it is more complex, you may want to define stricter methods to contain the logic.*

No matter how you specifically implement the identification logic, the responsibility of identifying the correct concrete class should be encapsulated in the factory, not the concrete classes themselves.

---

### A more generalized solution

It seems plausible to expect that the distinction logic may need to be expanded upon so it doesn't always rely on a simple `Contains` check, at which point you could change the key from being a `string` to becoming a `Func<data, bool>` which can define *any* logic you need it to.

If that is the case, this is a simple variation on the above example:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Func<string, bool>, Func<string, Base>> mappings = new Dictionary<Func<string, bool>, Func<string, Base>>()
{
    { data => data.Length == 15, data => new A(data) },
    { data => data.Contains("Bar"), data => new B(data) },
}

public Base CreateItem(string data)
{
    foreach(var mapping in mappings)
    {
        var isMappingCorrect = mapping.Key;
        if(isMappingCorrect(data))
        {
            var createItemMethod = mapping.Value;
            return createItemMethod(data);
        }

        throw new Exception("No mapping was found!");
    }
}
```

Now you are able to define custom logic for every concrete type, for cases when this is necessary. It also allows you to define more than one mapping for the same concrete type, as you can have multiple entries which all yield a result of the same concrete type.

*As an aside, feel free to use a custom class to represent this mapping instead of a key-value-pair. The examples here are kept simple for the sake of clarity. Further improvements can be added as necessary.*

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make such a detailled and didactic answer to a not-so-good question :)

Answer (score -1):

Re-posting my answer from CR:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/239511/212100

You don't need `A` and `B` at all.

Just let the `Base` class be concrete, from your obfuscated code it look like it should just carry the substring and therefore can actually be replaced by a string entirely. But I know that's not your real code so maybe you need it, I don't know.

Anyway the creation is polymorhic thing here, not the result.

```
public class Factory
{
    private IDictionary<string, Func<string, string>> fingerprints;

    public NotTheAbstractBase CreateItem(string data){
        foreach (var fingerprint in Fingerprints)
        {
           if (data.Contains(fingerprint.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           {
              return new NotTheAbstractBase(fingerprint.Value(data));
           }
        }
        throw new Exception("No fingerprint match");
    }
}

var dict = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>>();
dict["Foo"] = (x) => x.Substring(0,2);
dict["Bar"] = (x) => x.Substring(x.Length - 2, 2);
var factory = new Factory(dict);
```

You could use an interface of your own instead of `Func<string, string>` to make it more explicit...